Changing the page numbering style from the frontmatter to mainmatter in a thesis
I'm writing my MSc thesis. Everything is fine except one thing: I need the page numbering to be centered at the bottom for all pages in \frontmatter and to keep the page numbering style as define (in my code) for \mainmatter. Here is the portion of my code the concerns the problem:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in, headsep=22pt,footskip=0.75cm 
 ]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase{\rightorleftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\hspace{0.1cm} #1}{}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\S\thesection.\hspace{0.25cm}#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rightorleftmark}{%
 \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\rightmark}%
  \ifx\x\@empty
   \endgroup\leftmark
  \else
   \endgroup\rightmark
  \fi}
\makeatother

%==============================================================
% THIS MAKES THE PAGE NUMBER ON THE RIGHT SIDE OF FOOTER IN EACH CHAPTER TITLE PAGE
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Do the following three things in your document/code:

Define separate header styles for your front/main matter. Each setting starts by clearing everything before using commands for setting the update layout:
% Front matter page style
\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%
  \typeout{Setting front matter page style}%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  % <other header/footer settings>
}
% Main matter page style
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
  \typeout{Setting main matter page style}%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  % <other header/footer settings>
}

The \typeout commands writes content to the .log and can be used for debugging purposes, like ensuring that the code is executed at the correct location.
For your specific needs, you can add \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} to the frontmatter page style.

Add these updated page styles as part of the calls to \frontmatter and \mainmatter.
\AddToHook{cmd/frontmatter/after}{\pagestyle{frontmatter}}% Set front matter page style
\AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{\pagestyle{mainmatter}}% Set main matter page style

The above code adds hooks (code) to be executed after the \frontmatter and \mainmatter commands. Specifically, they would set the respective page styles.

Use \frontmatter and \mainmatter within your document code to delineate the division. This will ensure an appropriate call to the respective page style will update the way the header/footer is displayed.


Here is a template summarising the above suggestion:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%
  \typeout{Setting front matter page style}%
  \fancyhf{}% Remove header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  % <other header/footer setup>
}
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
  \typeout{Setting main matter page style}%
  \fancyhf{}% Remove header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  % <other header/footer setup>
}

\AddToHook{cmd/frontmatter/after}{\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{frontmatter}}
\AddToHook{cmd/mainmatter/after}{\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{mainmatter}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\chapter{Last chapter}\lipsum[1-5]
\section{First section}\lipsum[6-10]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[11-15]
\section{Third section}\lipsum[16-20]
\section{Last section}\lipsum[21-25]

\end{document}


You can keep the redefinition of the plain page style, as this is issued with every \chapter. However, you could also define this as a separate page style:
\fancypagestyle{chapter}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove footer rule
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}
\NewCommandCopy{\oldchapter}{\chapter}% Copy \chapter into \oldchapter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{ s O{#3} m }{% Update \chapter
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldchapter*{#3}}% \chapter*{...}
    {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}% \chapter[..]{...}
  \thispagestyle{chapter}% Update page style for this page only
}

This allows you the freedom to redefine it as needed. It's not possible to just add a hook to the end of \chapter (as in, \AddToHook{cmd/chapter/after}{\thispagestyle{chapter}}) since \chapter performs a number of steps to consume its arguments, leaving the hook to be executed prematurely as part of the argument collection. As such, a redefinition of \chapter with an overt \thispagestyle{chapter} at the end will ensure proper page style changes.

book provides a switch \if@mainmatter that is \iftrue in the main matter and \iffalse in the front matter (and the back matter). So you can use this in the definition of the page styles:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in, headsep=22pt,footskip=0.75cm 
 ]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\makeatletter
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\if@mainmatter\thepage\fi}
\fancyfoot[C]{\if@mainmatter\else\thepage\fi}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small\nouppercase{\rightorleftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\small\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\if@mainmatter\thechapter.\hspace{0.1cm} \fi#1}{}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\S\thesection.\hspace{0.25cm}#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand{\rightorleftmark}{%
 \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\rightmark}%
  \ifx\x\@empty
   \endgroup\leftmark
  \else
   \endgroup\rightmark
  \fi}

%==============================================================
% THIS MAKES THE PAGE NUMBER ON THE RIGHT SIDE OF FOOTER IN EACH CHAPTER TITLE PAGE
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\if@mainmatter\thepage\fi}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\if@mainmatter\else\thepage\fi}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{My First Chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}

In this example I've added also a condition for using \thechapter. \hspace{0.1cm} in the page header of the front matter to make the (not) numbering consistent with the chapter title in the front matter.
